# Can the support of a coherent sheaf be a numerically trivial divisor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety with Picard number 1 over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ such that $c_1(F)$ is algebraically trivial, and hence numerically trivial. Also rank $F=0$.

So $F$ is supported on a proper closed subscheme of $X$. Can $F$ be supported on a divisor, or is the codimension of Support $ F\geq 2$.

Since the Picard number of $X$ is 1, any non-zero effective divisor is ample. Since $c_1(F)$ is numerically trivial, if $F$ is supported on a divisor, it is non-effective. Is this possible?

Note, I [posted this question on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487013/167197), but have not received any answers.

Comment: Your hypothesis that $F$ has rank $0$ and $c_1(F)$ is numerically trivial is enough to conclude that $F$ cannot be supported on a divisor. (The Picard number 1 hypothesis is not necessary for this.)

Comment: @ulrich, thank you for the clarification. It would be helpful if you can elaborate a bit.

Comment: @ulrich, I have been trying to understand what you said. Do we have that - if we have a numerically trivial divisor $D$, then it cannot be the support of any sheaf. Is it because the $D$ is not effective?

Comment: Yes, the point is that on a projective variety a nonzero effective divisor is never numerically trivial.